# display picture from url and repeat this for 3 pictures

Tags: javascript

I ve been trying to find a way to reapeat the script so i can get 3 photos to display on click and insert of a url. The code below works for the first picture but i cant work out how to make it display the 2nd picture,,at moment the url populates the 2nd input but displays no picture..

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Photo 1</label> 

   <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon" ><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-camera pink  "></i></span> 
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" id="#" alt="Image Preview" width="247" height="142"/>
</div></div></form></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp" ).change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

</script>





<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Photo 2</label> 

   <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
<div class="input-group" >
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera pink"></i></span> 
<form id="form1" runat="server" >

    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />

    <img id="blah" id="#" alt="Image Preview" width="247" height="142"/>
</div></div></form></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp" ).change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both photo1 and photo2 have same id for form "form1", img "blah" and input "imgInp". Please fix this. Id's need to unique across the entire page.
Can you try assigning different ids to all the HTML.

And you should not repeat script like that blindly. try reusing code.

```js
  function readURL(input, imgID) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $(imgID).attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("#imgInp1" ).change(function(){
        readURL(this, "#blah1");
    });

      $("#imgInp2" ).change(function(){
        readURL(this, "#blah2");
    });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Photo 1</label> 

   <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon" ><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-camera pink  "></i></span> 
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <input type='file' id="imgInp1" />
    <img id="blah1" id="#" alt="Image Preview" width="247" height="142"/>
</div></div></form></div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Photo 2</label> 

   <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
<div class="input-group" >
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera pink"></i></span> 
<form id="form2" runat="server" >

    <input type='file' id="imgInp2" />

    <img id="blah2" id="#" alt="Image Preview" width="247" height="142"/>
</div></div></form></div>
```

Comment: thank you.. i feel dirty asking. but i will learn , thanks for the  informed answer .

Comment: We have all been there..if you are just starting out checkout codecamp and go through their tutorial once.